# R Caret using Recipe - Unable to create model using recipe functionality of caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a dataframe with 1560 samples (rows) and four features (columns) and one column with the class (TRUE/ FALSE).

Unfortunately the dataframe is too large to give you a reproducible sample. Any general help would be appreciated though!

When I now run the caret train() function,

```
lr_original <- train(original_data$class, original_data[,1:4], method='glm',metric = 'Accuracy', trControl= trainControl(method='cv', savePredictions = TRUE))
```

I get the error **Error in table(y) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements**

I already tried different sampling methods (LOOCV and none) as well as different classifying methods (knn and svm) - always the same error.

Is 1560 rows too much for the train function? Is there any way around it?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interchanged x and y in the train function.

With

```
lr_original <- train(original_data[,1:4],original_data$class, method='glm',metric = 'Accuracy', trControl= trainControl(method='cv', savePredictions = TRUE))
```

it works :)